# Does static pressure(p - p∞) at wing surface change exponentially, with square of the velocity?

Tags: aerodynamics, pitot-static

Integration of static pressure over wing we get lift.

and

Formula for lift is L= 1/2 x Cl x A x V2 x ro;
that implies that static pressure (p - p∞) change exponentially(as square of velocity), becuase A, Cl and ro dont change with velocity in attached flow regime.

One end of differential manometer I connect to small hole that I drill at upper wing surface(hole is drilled perpedicular to wing surface), other end connect to static port. Manometer  show  -400Pa at 100km/h, does it mean at 150km/h will be -900Pa, at 200km/h = -1600Pa etc ?

Does static pressure (p - p∞) change as square of velocity, in attached flow regime?

Comment: Static pressure is constant w.r.t. velocity (by definition). Do you mean dynamic pressure? Or total pressure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image][Pic source](https://www.baylor.edu/content/services/document.php/41147.pdf)

Indicated static pressure changes proportionally to the square of velocity. Static pressure around an airfoil depends on which point the pressure is measured, and is described as pressure coefficient at a location on the chord. The pressure coefficient is:

$$c_p = \frac{p - p_∞}{q_∞} => p = c_p * q_∞ + p_∞$$

p is the local pressure a particular point on the wing surface. The dynamic pressure $q_∞$ changes with the square of the velocity, but the static pressure has quite a large contribution to the equation. At sea level, with $p_∞$ = 101325 N/m^2 and $\rho$ = 1.225 kg/m$^3$:

[image]

Comment: Is pressure coeficient  constant with velocity? If yes,  differential manometer show   "delta pressure"(static pressure wing - static  pressure freestream) = Cp x dynamic pressure, so If Cp is constant then " delta pressure" rise with square of velocity.  Am I correct?

Comment: Indeed, delta pressure rises with the square of velocity, and then the surrounding pressure is added.

Comment: Yes only if we assume that Cp remain constant with velocity. But Cp change with Re number so this is not 100% accurate..

Comment: You can edit your answer because differential manometer show  delta pressure  (p - p∞).